# Is there a way to bulk/batch download all repos from Github based on a search result?

Tags: github, github-api

I run this search on Guthub and I get 881 repos. Blazor & C# repos.
https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=blazor&type=Repositories

Is there a way to download all these repos easily instead of one by one?

Comment: Why not parse the response html for repo paths and create download links which you run with curl or similar?

Comment: Because I don't want to do all that work if there's something out there that does it already.

Comment: A quick google search finds this as an example: https://github.com/BeameryHQ/git-beam-it. But questions to recommend or find a book, tool, ... are not a programming question and seem off-topic.

Comment: @tkruse I didn't ask for a tool or a recommendation. I asked for a way. A way could be a programming example or instructions from GitHub API. If an answerer wants to mention a tool, it's their choice. The question is related to Github and its API. Not all SO question must be pure programming only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your query can be run via the github search api:

- https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=blazor+language:C%23&per_page=100&page=1

That gives you one page of 100 repositories. You can loop over all pages, extract the ssh_url (or http if you prefer), and write the result to a file:

```sh
# cheating knowing we currently have 9 pages
for i in {1..9}
do
    curl "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=blazor+language:C%23&per_page=100&page=$i" \
     | jq -r '.items[].ssh_url' >> urls.txt
done

cat urls.txt | xargs -P8 -L1 git clone
```

You can optimize to extract the number of pages from the response headers.

References:

- https://developer.github.com/v3/search/
- [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)
- [How to apply shell command to each line of a command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711001/how-to-apply-shell-command-to-each-line-of-a-command-output)
- [Running programs in parallel using xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357997/running-programs-in-parallel-using-xargs)

Similar question:

- [GitHub API - Different number of results for jq filtered response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228774/github-api-different-number-of-results-for-jq-filtered-response)