# There is a way to batch archive GitHub repositories based off of a search?

Tags: github, github-api

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56336835/3970701) to a related question I know it's possible to batch clone repositories based on a GitHub search result:

```
# cheating knowing we currently have 9 pages
for i in {1..9}
do
    curl "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=blazor+language:C%23&per_page=100&page=$i" \
     | jq -r '.items[].ssh_url' >> urls.txt
done

cat urls.txt | xargs -P8 -L1 git clone
```

I also know that the [Hub](https://hub.github.com/) client allows me to make [API calls](https://hub.github.com/hub-api.1.html).

> hub api [-it] [-X METHOD] [-H HEADER] [--cache TTL] ENDPOINT [-F FIELD|--input FILE]

I guess the last step is, how do I archive a repository with Hub?

Comment: You can use this [graphQL endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#archiverepository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a repository using the [Update a Repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#update-a-repository) API call.

I put all my repositories in a `TMP` variable in the following way, and ran the following:

```
echo $TMP | xargs -P8 -L1 hub api -X PATCH -F archived=true
```

Here is a sample of what the `$TMP` variable looked like:

```
echo $TMP
/repos/amingilani/9bot
/repos/amingilani/advent-of-code-2019
/repos/amingilani/alan
/repos/amingilani/annotate_models
```